# Sending listing user an email (undefined variable or method 'email')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I'm currently trying to develop the following functionality: Users can list listings. Others can click on these listings, click apply, fill out a form and click on submit. This form should of course be send to the listing user. I am stuck on getting this last part right. I'm working with ActionMailer and this is what I got:

listing_controller.rb

```
def apply
      end

    def send_resume_email
        UserMailer.new_resume(@user).deliver
        redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message sent'
    end
```

apply.html.erb

```
<div class="top">
<div class="container-content">
    <div class="container">
        <%= form_tag(send_resume_email_path) do %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= label_tag 'name', 'Name' %>
                <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Your Name' %>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <%= label_tag 'email', 'Email' %>
               <%= email_field_tag 'email', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Your Email Address' %>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <%= label_tag 'comments', 'Comments' %>
               <%= text_area_tag 'comments', nil, class: 'form-control', rows: 4, placeholder: 'Comments...' %>
           </div>
           <%= submit_tag nil, class: 'btn btn-default btn-about pull-right' %>
       <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
 match '/send_resume_email', to: 'listings#send_resume_email', via: 'post'
```

user_mailer.rb

```
def new_resume(user)
    @user = user
    @url = 'http://www.example.com'
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Thanks for the awesome site')
end
end
```

new_resume.html.rb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>You've got a new resume, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You've got a new resume.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently I'm getting this error
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #14):

```
@user = user
@url = 'http://www.example.com'
mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Thanks for the awesome site')
```

end

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't defining `@user` in your controller, so it's nil.

So you're passing nil into the mailer, instead of a user record.

Your mailer is then trying to mail to `user.email`, which is `nil.email`, which gives you the error 'undefined method email for nil:NilClass'.

Comment: okay that makes sense. So if I do 
def send_resume_email
   @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
      UserMailer.new_resume(@user).deliver
      redirect_to findjobs_path, notice: 'Message  sent'
  end

The email is sent to my actual email address and not the email address of the user who listed the post? Do you happen to know why?

Comment: because for some reason `params[:id]` is your user ID, not the person you're trying to send it to. I don't know what user you want to send it to - I don't know enough about your application.

Comment: hey @sevenseacat,  Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/pblogs/e202ee1f03339ba977ec also updated the original post with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577753/rails-returning-several-duplicate-records-when-using-ajax