# Rails returning several duplicate records when using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app that has several movie clips and users can search for specific topics etc... I'm using Ajax to handle pagination so that users can make a search query and scroll to view more results (similar to twitter).

The issue is when a user searches for i.e. "Funny" a bunch of records will come up and as the user scrolls down Ajax will load duplicates of the records a long with new records.

Here's the code:

```
if $('.pagination').length
  $(window).scroll ->
    url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
    if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
      $('.loader').removeClass('hidden')
      $.getScript(url)
  $(window).scroll()
```

Here's an screenshot [image: Example]

How can I prevent rails from duplicating records in this case? I've tried uniq and several other methods to no avail.

Thanks!

**Update** here's some additional code that may be helpful in debugging this:

https://gist.github.com/pblogs/e202ee1f03339ba977ec

Answer (score 0):

To debug this issue, you really have to look at whether it's a javascript or a Rails problem

It seems from your debugging that your browser is sending two separate requests to your controller, which would denote that you have some sort of javascript issue. However, I've encountered Rails sending back "multiple" responses before as well

The key to solving the issue will be to determine what is causing the issue:

---

**JS**

If it's a JS problem, there are two potential issues you'll have:

> 1. Turbolinks
> 2. Your script firing twice

Firstly, I would ensure Turbolinks is not playing a problem here:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee

#Paginate
paginate = ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        $('.loader').removeClass('hidden')
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()

$(document).on "page:load ready", paginate
```

This will ensure the call is only called once per page load (it ties into [Turbolinks Hooks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events)). This means that if you want to ensure Turbolinks will not fire twice after partially reloading the page, it will do so.

Secondly, you want to ensure your script is only going to be called once. Specifically, I would investigate this line:

```
if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
```

This determines when the script will fire. You need to make sure that the scroll is only called once, which this line will determine.

--

**Rails**

The second potential point of concern will be Rails.

If you're sending a request to Rails, you need to appreciate that may have a tendency to send back multiple responses if something like Turbolinks gets in the way

I would make sure my controller is set up as such:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def your_action
      ...
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js
         format.html
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: I've set up the controller method with proper `respond_to` formats, I've used the script provided by you in the answer, but still we get the same 2 requests, I am sure we have Jquery library loaded only once in our app, we don't have turbolinks enabled.. I've used this technique for infinite scrolling and never had a bug like this. Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: No problem - have you looked at the requests specifically (IE what was sent?) Another thing to do would be to define an alert when the function it called -- allowing you to see if it's the function which is being called twice

Comment: Strange thing, when I use `alert` the function is triggered only once, so basically I have one request per page load, no more double requests. Any idea on this?

Comment: By the way. I added alert directly after if statement and using your script

Comment: Okay, is the `if` statement the `if url` or `if $().length`?

Comment: Oh sorry, the `if url` I was talking about. https://gist.github.com/rmagnum2002/a59a2d5aac21a835f035

Comment: Thanks @RichPeck, any help here would be great!

Comment: This remains an un-solved mystery. Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are replacing contents instead of appending another set of results to existing ones in your .js.erb

Comment: Thanks @iouri, the issue with this is I don't want to replace existing results but rather have new results added below the existing results as your scroll. Your method solves the duplicate issue, but also removes the prior results, in our case we'd like to show the totality of results for any given query.

Comment: I think we identified the issue in IRC, scroll was firing multiple times so it was getting requests for the same page before last requests finished loading. Suggestion was to add a logical toggle of some sort to pause processing until index.js.erb finished loading, then enable it again after it's done. Maybe use loader hidden as a flag to load/not load next page, etc.